# mysql in docker secure-file-priv problems

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, docker

mysql in docker on windows with python, local

---

`LOAD DATA INFILE...`
query gets the pymysql 1290 error, 'The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement'

---

`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';` in powershell shows 'NULL'

---

tried `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...` as found as possible solution

get pymysql error 3948, 'Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides'

---

found different solutions saying:

-'secure_file_priv' shouldn't be a path, should be NULL

-'secure_file_priv' must be empthy, (= "")

did not found how to acces mysql 'my.ini' configfile in docker to change...

---

does someone now a definitive solution? (i'm working only local)